# How to parse Google Sheets query (show only the first column)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to show only the first result from column (G) of the output of this query:

`=QUERY(data!A1:O7122; "SELECT G, COUNT(G) WHERE E = '"&A3&"' GROUP BY G LABEL G '', COUNT(G) ''";0)`

So I tried this:

`=INDEX(QUERY(data!A1:O7122; "SELECT G, COUNT(G) WHERE E = '"&A3&"' GROUP BY G LABEL G '', COUNT(G) ''";0), 1, 1)`

But it doesn't work (error). Any idea...? :)

Comment: Do you have sample data with desired output, it will be easier to know how to solve it.

Comment: Adding "LIMIT 1" to the end of your QUERY's SELECT clause should work. However, I also have to wonder why you are querying A1:O7122 if you're only referencing E:G. That is, it seems to me that `QUERY(data!E:G; ...` is all you need and will therefore be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @Kin Siang and Erik Tyler; here is the sample data:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YHX_HlgFZC2S_vCdDMkROb-DeOT1rpvN0apIlN-6SIY/edit?usp=sharing

The query i'm trying to fix is in E3.

Comment: (in the "data2" sheet). I'm trying to show only the first column of the first result, without displaying the count in F3.

Answer (score 0):

I can display your expected output with slight adjustment on your formula as following, although I do not use your raw data for calculation:

`=index(QUERY(data!A1:O18, "SELECT G, Count(G) WHERE E = '"&A1&"' Group By G Order by Count(G) Desc Label Count(G) ''",0),1,1)`

[image]

Comparison without `index` as following:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and adjustment!
Nonetheless, I keep having an error in the formula and can't understand where it is coming from?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YHX_HlgFZC2S_vCdDMkROb-DeOT1rpvN0apIlN-6SIY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try share edit right or you can create a new sheet with less data and share the sheet with edit right? I can use the formula on my sheet without any issue, fyi.

Comment: You can edit the file now!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YHX_HlgFZC2S_vCdDMkROb-DeOT1rpvN0apIlN-6SIY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've been struggling all the morning to find out the issue without being able to solve it..

Comment: Ya, you need to use semi colon `=index(QUERY(data!A1:O7122; "SELECT G, Count(G) WHERE E = '"&A4&"' Group By G Label Count(G) ''";0);1;1)`, I am trying to sort the data to show top value on first row.

Comment: Try my edit answer to sort your result, remember to replace colon `',' with semi-colon `;` in your case

Comment: You're great, @Kin! It's working perfectly now.
Last question, in case you can/want help me on this one too.. I'm trying now in column G to add a where clause on the year but no result is found. Nonetheless, you can see in the data sheet that there are results for year 2018 on those products. Any idea?

Comment: Probably you should open another thread for your issue...

Comment: Ok, thanks I opened a new topic there :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552682/google-sheets-query-unexpected-empty-result-in-the-output

Comment: Glad that others is solving the issue, you may accept the answer if helping you :)